# How to filter data from 1 table using another while getting information from second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

TABLE1:

```
C1 | MORECOLUMNS
----------------
aa | info1
aa | info2
bb | info3
bb | info4
cc | info5
```

TABLE2:

```
C1 | C2 | C3
------------
aa | 31 | x
cc | 46 | y
```

I need to get all rows from table1 that have corresponding C1 in table2 along with info from table2
output:

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | MORECOLUMNS
--------------------------
aa | 31 | x | info1
aa | 31 | x | info2
cc | 46 | y | info5
```

How should I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pretty standard `INNER JOIN`:

```
select t1.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3, t1.morecolumns
from table1 t1
   join table2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.C1, b.C2,b.C3,a.MORECOLUMNS
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.C1 = b.C1
```

Plenty of information out and about regarding JOINS, one source is: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing at least some some cursory research on SQL!

Ex.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

> **SQL JOIN**
>
> An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables,
>   based on a common field between them.
>
> The most common type of join is: SQL INNER JOIN (simple join). An SQL
>   INNER JOIN return all rows from multiple tables where the join
>   condition is met.